# Cyberduck sync bookmarks with Google Drive failing

Tags: ftp, sync, bookmarks, cyberduck

I'm trying to overwrite the default folder from cyberduck to store my bookmarks in a google drive folder. I found this question on cyberduck self: https://trac.cyberduck.io/ticket/6377#comment:4

With a little digging I found this article: https://stewartadam.io/blog/2014/05/05/sharing-your-cyberduck-bookmarks-between-computers-coud-sync-dropbox-google-drive-or

So i'm trying to overwrite te settings via terminal:

$ `defaults write ch.sudo.cyberduck application.support.path ~/Google Drive/Cyberduck`

I'm getting this error:

```
2020-12-02 15:03:14.864 defaults[46340:11519935] Unexpected argument Drive/Werk/Obaia/Cyberduck; leaving defaults unchanged.
```

It's crashing over the whitespace in Google Drive, I've tried the following with no success:

```
defaults write ch.sudo.cyberduck application.support.path ~/Google\ Drive/Cyberduck
defaults write ch.sudo.cyberduck application.support.path "~/Google Drive/Cyberduck"
```

Anyone tackled this issue? please let me know

Answer (score 0):

It looks like things have since changed, as MacOS added app containerization which broke the old way of syncing bookmarks. The application support path is no longer customizable as Cyberduck on MacOS now saves its app data to `~/Library/Group Containers/G69SCX94XU.duck/Library/Application Support/duck/` (per [Cyberduck FAQ](https://trac.cyberduck.io/wiki/help/en/faq#Preferencesandapplicationsupportfileslocation)).

I just gave it a try and symlinking the Bookmarks folder to an external directory does work, so that's your best bet, e.g.:

```sh
mv ~/Library/Group\ Containers/G69SCX94XU.duck/Library/Application\ Support/duck/Bookmarks ~/Dropbox/Cyberduck-Bookmarks
ln -s ~/Dropbox/Cyberduck-Bookmarks ~/Library/Group\ Containers/G69SCX94XU.duck/Library/Application\ Support/duck/Bookmarks
```